# Encontrar todas las combinaciones posibles de sección-orden con suma

Tags: mysql, sql

En mi aplicación, los usuarios pueden elegir el orden en el que se mostrarán las secciones (tanto de forma personal como para el departamento en el que trabajan). Para guardar esta información tengo dos tablas (simplificadas):

```
seccion            ordenseccion
--------------     --------------
id                 id
nombre             usarioid
orden              tipo
                   seccionid
                   orden
```

Donde `seccion` es la tabla con las secciones disponibles, con su id, nombre y orden por defecto. Y `ordenseccion` guarda los datos del usuario (su id), el tipo de ordenacion ("personal" o "departamento") el id de la sección y el orden en el que se debe mostrar.

Y que podría contener la siguiente información (ejemplo [disponible también en SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7825b6)):

```
SECCION
id     nombre     orden
------ ---------- ---------
1      A          1
2      B          2
3      C          3

ORDENSECCION
id     usuarioid     tipo             seccionid     orden
------ ------------- ---------------- ------------- ---------
1      1234          PERSONAL         1             3
2      1234          PERSONAL         2             2
3      1234          PERSONAL         3             1
4      5678          PERSONAL         1             1
5      5678          PERSONAL         2             3
6      5678          PERSONAL         3             2
7      5678          DEPARTAMENTO     1             2
8      5678          DEPARTAMENTO     2             1
9      5678          DEPARTAMENTO     3             3
```

Las secciones se mostrarán con el orden por defecto especificado en `seccion`, a menos que el usuario haya indicado una ordenación diferente en `ordenseccion`. Así, el usuario 1234 verá las secciones en el orden CBA, el usuario 5678 verá las secciones en el orden ACB, y los trabajadores del departamento de 5678 verán las secciones en orden BAC.

Código para recrear la base de datos:

```sql
CREATE TABLE seccion(
  id INTEGER(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombre VARCHAR(20),
  orden INTEGER(10),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE ordenseccion(
  id INTEGER(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  usuarioid INTEGER(10),
  tipo VARCHAR(20),
  seccionid INTEGER(10),
  orden INTEGER(10),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO seccion (nombre, orden) VALUES ('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3);

INSERT INTO ordenseccion (usuarioid, tipo, seccionid, orden) 
VALUES (1234, 'PERSONAL', 1, 3),
       (1234, 'PERSONAL', 2, 2),
       (1234, 'PERSONAL', 3, 1),
       (5678, 'PERSONAL', 1, 1),
       (5678, 'PERSONAL', 2, 3),
       (5678, 'PERSONAL', 3, 2),
       (5678, 'DEPARTAMENTO', 1, 2),
       (5678, 'DEPARTAMENTO', 2, 1),
       (5678, 'DEPARTAMENTO', 3, 3);
```

---

Por motivos estadísticos, quiero saber el orden personal seleccionado por los diferentes usuarios (cuando el tipo es "PERSONAL") para ponerlo en una gráfica de barras apilada. Para ello quiero obtener una cuenta de todas las secciones y la posición en la que aparecen. Es decir, quiero obtener algo como esto:

```
SECCION      POS1     POS2     POS3
------------ -------- -------- --------
A            1        0        1 
B            0        1        1
C            1        1        0
```

---

He intentado con algo como esto:

```sql
SELECT   s.nombre,
         os.orden,
         COUNT(os.orden)         
FROM     seccion s LEFT JOIN ordenseccion os ON os.seccionid = s.id
WHERE    os.tipo = 'PERSONAL'
GROUP BY s.nombre, os.orden
ORDER BY s.nombre;
```

Pero no me termina de devolver todos los datos, solamente una versión reducida de los mismos y no agrupada de la manera que busco:

```
SECCION     POS     COUNT
----------- ------- ---------
A           1       1
A           3       1
B           2       1
B           3       1
C           1       1
C           2       1
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener los datos incluso de secciones que no tienen esa posición? (con COUNT=0; p.e. sección 0, posición 2, count 0). Debe ser haciendo el JOIN de manera diferente, pero no consigo dar con la tecla. Es decir, quiero algo como esto:

```
SECCION     ORDEN     COUNT
----------- --------- ---------
A           1         1
A           2         0
A           3         1
B           1         0
B           2         1
B           3         1
C           1         1
C           2         1
C           3         0
```

O, si existiría alguna manera de obtener una matriz como la descrita arriba. Teniendo en cuenta que el número de secciones (y por tanto de posiciones) podría variar en el tiempo. La idea es que luego el resultado se pasaría a JSON y a un plugin que genere la gráfica.

Comment: Para que te salgan los resultados como columnas hacia el lado, no tengo claro cómo se hace (alguna vez lo vi en SQL, pero no en Mysql), pero mientras, y hablando de por qué no te muestra el `COUNT()` de las secciones que debieran decir "cero", es porque estás filtrando por un campo de la tabla al lado derecho del `LEFT JOIN` (el `WHERE os.tipo = 'PERSONAL'`): debes aplicar ese filtro mejor dentro del `FROM`, para que no te cruce las tablas completamente. Y lo mismo, en el `GROUP BY`: solicitas una columna de la tabla `ordenseccion`. En este último caso, mejor agrupa por `s.nombre, s.orden`.

Comment: @quinqui, ¿podrías indicarme cómo sería la consulta con esos cambios? No tengo claro lo de ordenar por `s.orden`, aunque creo que la ordenación no afectaría (mientras los ordenes estén en el mismo orden dentro de la sección).

Comment: ¿Te lo indico por chat, mejor? Digo, porque lo que te sugerí, es una ayuda, pero no responde al 100% tu pregunta, como para escribir una "respuesta"...

Comment: @quinqui Como quieras, aunque si devuelve los ordenes que no existen con 0, me vale como respuesta, lo de obtener los datos como matriz sería conveniente, pero tampoco es necesario.

Comment: ¿Cuantas secciones podría tener un usuario? ¿Es un número determinado o variable?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho las secciones van a ser las mismas para todos los usuarios (número fijo), aunque podrían cambiar con el tiempo (p.e. se podría añadir una sección D o eliminar la sección B). El ejemplo de arriba es una versión simplificada y son 3, pero en realidad son las secciones de un XML y son alrededor de 60 (si fueran sólo 3, me planteaba hacer tres `SELECT COUNT` por cada una de ellas, ¿pero con 60?).

Comment: Entonces (y ya que no se puede abrir chat de forma manual -_-), te voy a escribir mi idea en una respuesta ;)

Comment: En SQL server, tienes `PIVOT`, no se si en mysql tienes algo similar. Sino la otra opción que eventualmente se puede investigar, es la de construir una sentencia dinámica en base a la cantidad de secciones y luego ejecutarla.

Comment: @quinqui Perdón, no me había dado cuenta que no podías abrir salas de chat. Entra en [ésta](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75153/sql-consulta-suma)

Comment: (Intento hacer las pruebas en SQLFiddle, pero se queda pegado, y me toca reiniciar cada vez el sitio.... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero te sirva esta solución que se ajusta perfectamente al resultado que buscas. Lo que hago en la consulta es tener como tabla principal a `seccion` para despues hacer un `inner join`  con todas las posibles combinaciones de **seccion y orden** (hago el `select distinct` de la tabla `seccion` para tener los posibles numeros de la columna `orden`). Después hago el `left join` con la tabla `ordenseccion` para hacer el conteo de cuantos coinciden con la combinación de **seccion y orden** y agrupo  por nombre y orden para que se realice el conteo correspondiente.

```
SELECT   sc.nombre,
         s.orden,
         COUNT(OS.ORDEN) COUNT
FROM    seccion sc 
INNER JOIN (select distinct orden from seccion ) s 
LEFT JOIN  ordenseccion os on os.orden =s.orden and os.seccionid = sc.id and tipo ="PERSONAL"
GROUP BY sc.NOMBRE, S.ORDEN
ORDER BY sc.NOMBRE, S.ORDEN
```

Answer (score 1):

Como te comenté, una forma bien sencilla de plantearlo es construir una sentencia dinámica y luego ejecutarla. El primer paso de todos es escribir la consulta real para resolver el problema actual asumiendo que tenemos solo tres secciones. Esto lo haríamos así:

```
SELECT s.nombre as  'SECCION',
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.orden=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as POS1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.orden=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as POS2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.orden=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as POS3
       from (SELECT DISTINCT tipo FROM ordenseccion) t
       CROSS JOIN seccion s
       left join ordenseccion o
            ON o.seccionid = s.id  and o.tipo = t.tipo
       WHERE t.tipo='PERSONAL'
       GROUP BY t.tipo, s.nombre
```

Si tuvieras (imagino que sí) una tabla para los distintos `tipos` de cada sección, simplemente reemplaza `(SELECT DISTINCT tipo FROM ordenseccion)` por el `select` correspondiente. La salida final de esta consulta sería algo así:

```
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| # | SECCION | POS1 | POS2 | POS3 |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 1 | A       | 1    | 0    | 1    |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 2 | B       | 0    | 1    | 1    |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 3 | C       | 1    | 1    | 0    |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
```

Ahora el siguiente paso es construir dinámicamente la consulta anterior pero teniendo en cuenta la parte variable que sería la tabla `seccion`

```
Select GROUP_CONCAT('       SUM(CASE WHEN o.orden=', rownum, ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as POS',rownum separator ',\n')
    INTO @SQL
    from (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, 
                 t.*
                 FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, 
                       seccion t 
                 order by id) as t1;

set @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT s.nombre as  \'SECCION\',\n',  @SQL, '\n       from (SELECT DISTINCT tipo FROM ordenseccion) t\n       CROSS JOIN seccion s\n       left join ordenseccion o\n            ON o.seccionid = s.id  and o.tipo = t.tipo\n       WHERE t.tipo=\'PERSONAL\'\n       GROUP BY t.tipo, s.nombre');
```

Notarás que hay varios espacios y `\n`, esto simplemente para que la consulta si la deseas imprimir se vea bien, todos esos caracteres se podrían obviar. La ejecución final sería:

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Algunos comentarios adicionales

- No conozco en profundidad MySQL, pero imagino que igual que otras bases de datos, este tipo de consultas no pueden ser optimizadas por el motor, justamente por ser dinámicas
- Seguramente hay límites en la cantidad de columnas que podamos agregar, ya sea por el tamaño de la variable `@SQL` o seguramente por algún límite en el tamaño de las filas ([ver](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html#row-size-limits)). Pero la mayor limitación es la de `GROUP_CONCAT()` que esta limitado a retornar 1024 caracteres. Esto eventualmente se podría llegar a ajustar así: `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;`

Te dejé un [fiddle](http://rextester.com/AJZZ43116) funcionando